# Help with configuring the humanoid rig, hands disconnected

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging

I am working on rigging my first unity character made in blender with the Rigify addon. I converted the rig into a unity ready one with the rigify to unity addon and imported my model but I'm having an issue where the finger and hand bones are not following the arms. I don't know how I'm supposed to configure the hierarchy, the rig works fine when animating but I'm not really sure what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the import settings of  the model into Unity? Is the model marked as humanoid? Is the avatar set up correctly?

Comment: yes I imported the fbx with only the deform bones checked, all the export settings were right in blender and when I tried to set up the rig in unity after selecting humanoid it will immediately enforce t-pose and the hands will be disconnted. to my knowledge everything should be right but I think the higherarchy is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.